# $K$ a local field, the spaces $K^n : n = 1, 2, ...$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-topology, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field.  If $K$ is archimedean, then one can distinguish the spaces topological spaces $K, K^2, K^3$ etc. by their homotopy groups.  How can one distinguish these spaces when $K$ is nonarchimedean?

Comment: are they really not homeomorphic? $K$ looks to me homeomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ times Cantor discontinuum, and so does $K^n$ (though I may be easily wrong)

Comment: You're right, I was doing the stupid thing on stackexchange where I answer my own question (actually, a friend pointed the answer out to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed out to me today, these spaces are actually homeomorphic when $K$ is nonarchimedean and of characteristic zero!

For example, take $K = \mathbb{Q}_p$.  It is known that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is homeomorphic to the cantor set $C$, and $C \simeq C^2$.  Thus there is a homeomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Let $k \leq 0$ be an integer.  Define a homeomorphism $\phi_k: p^k\mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow p^k\mathbb{Z}_p \times p^k\mathbb{Z}_p$ by $x \mapsto p^k \phi(\frac{1}{p^k}x)$.

Now $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the direct limit of the directed system of topological spaces $\mathbb{Z}_p \subseteq p^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_p \subseteq \cdots$, and similarly  $\mathbb{Q}_p \times \mathbb{Q}_p$ is the direct limit of the system $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \subseteq p^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_p \times p^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_p \subseteq \cdots$.

Then $\phi = \varinjlim \phi_k$ extends to a homeomorphism $\mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p^2$.